# Jenkins plugin installation via ansible unstable, ansible states success but does not perform any action

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins

I'm experiencing a strage behavior with my ansible playbook. I'm installing a jenkins server via YUM and add some plugins atferwards.

Basically my playbook works fine but most of the time I run into an issue with the plugins installation. Ansible says it is installing the plugins but the directory remains completely empty and the jenkins log does not show any sign of actually installing a plugin (normaly jenkins logs each plugin installation).

Ansible output from playbook

```sh
TASK [Install Plugins on behalf of jenkins user <THE_ADMIN_USER>] ****************************
task path: /home/pd03056a/ansible-playbooks/tasks/install-plugins-master.yml:2
changed: [<SERVERNAME>] => (item={u'key': u'ace-editor'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": true, "item": {"key": "ace-editor"}, "plugin": "ace-editor", "state": "present"}
changed: [<SERVERNAME>] => (item={u'key': u'active-directory'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": true, "item": {"key": "active-directory"}, "plugin": "active-directory", "state": "present"}
changed: [<SERVERNAME>] => (item={u'key': u'ant'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "attempts": 1, "changed": true, "item": {"key": "ant"}, "plugin": "ant", "state": "present"}
...
```

My tasklooks like this:

```sh
# Jenkins master: install plugins
- name: Install Plugins on behalf of jenkins user {{jenkins_admin_user}} (Servername = {{ inventory_hostname_short }})
  jenkins_plugin:
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    url: "http://{{ inventory_hostname_short }}:8080"
    url_username: "{{jenkins_admin_user}}"
    url_password: "{{jenkins_admin_pass}}"
  environment:
    http_proxy: "http://{{proxy_user}}:{{proxy_pass}}@<THE_SERVER>:80"
    https_proxy: "http://{{proxy_user}}:{{proxy_pass}}@<THE_SERVER>:80"
  register: plugin_result
  until: plugin_result is success
  retries: 10
  delay: 2
  with_items: # no version = latest
    - { key: "ace-editor"}
    - { key: "active-directory"}
    - { key: "ant"}
    - { key: "..."}
```

The contents of the directory right after running the playbook:

```sh
$ ls -al /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug 12 12:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug 12 12:57 ..
```

Directory is totally empty ... I deleted /var/lib/jenkins completely after each try so there is no way any old content remains on the HDD (`rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins`). I'm a little confused with the ansible message as well. For each plugin it says "changed". But how can something get changed after it was deleted entirely? I would expect something along the lines of "created" oder "added".

Then every once in a while (mostly after waiting some time) the playbook works perfectly normal with all plugins installations for no apparent reason. Maybe there is some kind of cache inside ansible causing this behavior? I'm grateful for any hint. Thanks guys and best regards. Sebastian

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: Actuallyusing Ansible I did not. But you can pass a textfile with a list of plugins and have Jenkins install them. Here is a Dockerfile where I did this: https://gitlab.com/sommerfeld.sebastian/docker-jenkins/-/blob/main/src/main/jenkins-master/Dockerfile ... other resources are in the same repo next to the Dockerfile.